# iOS detecting photo capture from default camera app in your app from background

Tags: ios

I want to be able to detect the camera capture event that happens from the default iOS camera app when my app is running in the background to do some processing.

I have seen Facebook Moments doing it. It throws notifications on capture after being in the suspended state for hours well after the 180 seconds that Apple allows any app to stay active at max after being put in background. Also they don't take location permissions. They don't do it based on silent APNS because it works without internet as well.

I have already explored PhotoLibraryChangeObserver in the Photos.framework but it works only when the app is brought into foreground.